# Шаблон "Наблюдатель" (Observer)

Tags: архитектура

Привет. Помогите разобраться с этим шаблоном. Что он из себя представляет и как его использовать.

Comment: На хабре достаточно инфы!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Пример: Есть компания CompanyA (Observer) и есть человек HumanA (Subject). 
CompanyA выпускает новости, эти новости интересны человеку HumanA.
Что бы получать их, он должен подписаться на эти новости для компании CompanyA. Для этого, человек HumanA должен реализовать метод, в который он будет получать новости от компании.
Компания же, должна реализовать методы: подписаться (Subscribe), отписаться (unscribe) которые любой объект (Subject) может использовать передавая в параметре себя. 
В Observer хранится  Array лист этих объектов (Subject).
При выходе новости в компании CompanyA, она оповещает всех субъектов (Subject) о том, что у нее вышла новость, для этого она передает в метод который они реализовали (пример: updateNews(News {String})) новость.  Subject получает эту новость в метод и делает с ней, что ему нужно.

Грубо говоря, это подписка как на события. При изменении в обсервере, он оповещает подписчиков, о том что произошло изменение, и отсылает данные (или не отсылает).

Есть еще хороший пример на [Википедии](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9D%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D1%8E%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C_(%D1%88%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F)#Java), метеорологическая станция. При изменении, она  отсылает значение температуры всем подписчикам (градусники и так дальше)

Comment: спасибо.БУДу разбираться.На хабре очень сложно написано для человека имеющего не сильные знания.Туда нужно итди уже с средней базой по даной теме

Comment: Может быть наоборот?: наблюдатель (он же observer, так же еще называемый слушателем) - это человек, который ждет новостей. Субъект (оповещатель) - это компания, которая выпускает новости. Наблюдатель-человек подписывается на новости и ждет. Компания-оповещатель через специальный механизм (интерфейс) оповещает всех, кто подписался. Ну и пример для понимания https://ru.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java/Listeners